# Query to invoke SQL agent Job with passing parameter from query in SQL server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005

Query to invoke SQL Job with passing parameter from query in SQL server 2005?

Comment: Please could you clarify what you are trying to do? It sounds like you want to start a SQL Agent job from a query, but it's not clear where the parameter is required. Is it the name of the job you want to start, a value you want to pass to a query run in the job, or something else?

Comment: Simply any parameter or without parameter, how can invoke sql job from the script? Please don't concentrate on parameter, just want to know invoke job on demand by query.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute this code to start an existing job:

EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_start_job N'Weekly Sales Data Backup' ;

-- This is documented in Books On Line(BOL). 
-- There are specific permission requirements to be abble to run this procedure.

I'm not sure what you mean by parameters.

Comment: I am talking about the parameter used in the query or sp which call from scheduled job.